# how to use nohup while still sending stderr to the terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, nohup

nohup automatically redirects stderr to stdout, but I want to send it to the terminal (it shows progress). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `nohup` manual states:

```
NAME
   nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty
```

It is used to run a command WITHOUT a tty asociated with it, you can end your session and the command will keep running, thus its output is not attached to a tty therefore not being able to show the output there. `nohup` creates a file named nohup.out though, you can access that file with `tail -f` from any terminal and keep whatching the command's output.

Answer (score 3):

Just redirect it. Take this script, for example which prints a line to stderr and one to stdout:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo stderr >&2
echo stdout
```

If I now run that with `nohup` and redirect standard error to a file, it works as expected:

```
$ nohup a.sh 2>er
$ cat er
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
stderr
```

Note that it also includes the stderr of `nohup` itself since you are redirecting output of the `nohup`. You can do the same with stdout:

```
nohup a.sh > foo
```

Basically, `nohup` only uses `nohup.out` when you don't redirect output.

---

To print stderr to the terminal, you can use [process redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to pass stderr through `tee`:

```
$ nohup a.sh 2> >(tee)
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
stderr
```

Comment: "how to use nohup while still sending stderr to the terminal"

Comment: @IttayD whops, true. See updated answer.

Comment: this will output to stdout

Comment: @IttayD yes, that's what you asked for. It prints stderr to the terminal, to stdout.